# Баба и бабочка

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Меня всегда интересовало: есть ли связь между словами "баба" и "бабочка"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, бабочка выводится из "бабка". Только не из многозначного "баба", а от конкретного "бабка", "бабушка".

ба́бочка

уменьш. от ба́бка "бабушка". Это образование основано на представлении, что душа умершего продолжает жить в виде бабочки; см. Потебня, РФВ 7, 69; Преобр. 1, 10. Ср. еще русск. диал. ду́шичка "бабочка" от душа́ (Горяев, ЭС 8), нов.-греч. ψυχάρι "бабочка": ψυχή "душа". Подробно см. Иммиш, Glotta 6, 193 и сл.
(Фасмер)

Answer (score 0):

Бабочка-(насекомое) Собств.-р. Образовано с помощью умен.ласк. суф. –очк от сущ.баба- «мотылек, бабочка»
Бабушка- Собств.-р. Образовано от сущ. баба- «мать отца или матери» с помощью умен.ласк. суф.-ушк.
Бабочка. Искон. Суф. производное от «баба» в значение «мотылёк, бабочка» (такое значение ещё отмечается в диалектах ). Баба «бабочка» - из баба «старуха, женщина». В основе названия насекомого лежит языческое представление о «вместилище» души предков женского пола. 
Следовательно, связь есть.

Comment: Насчет сцффикса - фактическая ошибка.
Мало того, что "суффикс" не очка, а -очк, так еще это два суффикса.
Первый -(о)к- перешел в -оч-, второй - -к-.
Сравните: корочка - от корка, а не от кора.